# mongodb - add field where the children has a field exist

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example of my MongoDb structure :

record 1 :

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "childID" : 1,
            "fruitList" : "orange" <-----
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 2,
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 3,
            "fruitList" : "apple" <-----
        },
        {
         .
         .
         .
        }
    ]
}
```

record 2 :

```
{
    "id" : 2,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "childID" : 1,
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 2,
            "fruitList" : "" <----- it's empty
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 3,
        },
        {
         .
         .
         .
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make a query update.. the query must add "hasFruit" => "true" to the record who has at least one children that have a fruit.... I mean, that the record has a field "fruitList" exist, and the value of that field is not empty

So, the records will be :

record 1 :

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "hasFruit" : true <-----
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "childID" : 1,
            "fruitList" : "orange"
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 2,
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 3,
            "fruitList" : "apple"
        },
        {
         .
         .
         .
        }
    ]
}
```

record 2 :

```
{
    "id" : 2,
    "hasFruit" : false <-----
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "childID" : 1,
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 2,
            "fruitList" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "childID" : 3,
        },
        {
         .
         .
     .
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean update via mongosb shell?

Comment: yes i want a bulk update from the shell

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. It filters records which have at least one children where fruitList exists and is not an empty string.

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
  {"children.fruitList" : {$exists: true, $ne: ""}}, 
  {$set: {hasFruit: true}}, 
  {multi: true}
)
```